# Comparing performance between custom implemented LINQ methods and the original

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I was just messing around implementing some of LINQ methods when I find out that some of the custom implementation actually run faster than the original even though the implementation is similar. Dealing with lists instead of arrays, makes the difference of speed even bigger to the side of the custom methods!

```
public static class CustomLINQ
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> WHERE<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
            if (predicate(item))
                yield return item;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TReturn> SELECT<TSource, TReturn>(this IEnumerable<TSource> items, Func<TSource, TReturn> projection)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
            yield return projection(item);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static int loops  = 1000000;
    static int nTests = 100;

    static void Measure(string msg, Action code)
    {
        long total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nTests; i++)
        {
            var w = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int j = 0; j < loops; j++)
                code();
            total += w.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("(avg) {0} \t {1}ms", msg, total / nTests);
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sample = new List<string> { "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight" };
        //var sample = new[] { "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight" };

        Measure("Linq Where", () =>    { var res = sample.Where(x => true && x.Length % 2 == 0); });
        Measure("Custom Where", () =>  { var res = sample.WHERE(x => true && x.Length % 2 == 0); });
        Measure("Linq Select", () =>   { var res = sample.Select(x => x.Length);                 });
        Measure("Custom Select", () => { var res = sample.SELECT(x => x.Length);                 });

    }
}
```

Sample Times:

(using a list)

```
(avg) Linq Where         102ms
(avg) Custom Where       62ms
(avg) Linq Select        122ms
(avg) Custom Select      59ms
```

(using an array)

```
(avg) Linq Where         75ms
(avg) Custom Where       60ms
(avg) Linq Select        77ms
(avg) Custom Select      60ms
```

The custom `Any` and `All` and the originals also performed slightly a bit differently although the implementation is almost exactly the same, I'm only interested in `Where` and `Select` for now

My questions:

- This makes me kind of doubt the way I'm measuring this, am I doing it right? is there something wrong with it?
- Why does this simple implementation seem to perform better than the originals? (almost twice as fast with lists and slightly faster with arrays)
- When dealing with lists, why is the difference in performance between the custom implementation and LINQs bigger than it is when dealing with arrays?

Comment: Why do you also meansure the creation of the `Stopwatch` instances and the measurement itself?

Comment: It didn't JIT `{ var res = sample.Where(x => true && x.Length % 2 == 0); }` only once, right? That would mean that time must be excluded from your first test.

Comment: 1) I don't see you evaluating the sequence. 2) LINQ has parameter validation, your methods don't. For short sequences (or if the resulting sequence isn't even evaluated) that validation overhead may be noticeable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't actually iterating the sequences. All you are testing is enumerator **creation** performance; not the actual loop. Basically, the test is meaningless.

For info, I tweaked this to:

```
Measure("Linq Where", () => { sample.Where(x => true && x.Length % 2 == 0).Consume(); });
Measure("Custom Where", () => { sample.WHERE(x => true && x.Length % 2 == 0).Consume(); });
Measure("Linq Select", () => { sample.Select(x => x.Length).Consume(); });
Measure("Custom Select", () => { sample.SELECT(x => x.Length).Consume(); });
```

using:

```
public static void Consume<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    using(var iter = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (iter.MoveNext()) { }
    }
}
```

(which just burns through an iterator manually), changed `loops` to `500000`, and retried (release mode, console, etc):

```
(avg) Linq Where         139ms
(avg) Custom Where       174ms
(avg) Linq Select        132ms
(avg) Custom Select      174ms
```

LINQ wins.

Comment: As @CodesInChaos noted, it's also worth noting that the actual LINQ implementation does more stuff, i.e. parameter validation...etc.

Comment: Can't we beat those LINQ times? I've looked around for a faster implementation or something but couldn't find any...

Comment: @vexe why are you trying to? do you have a specific reason to think that LINQ is a significant performance problem in your application? Hint: the LINQ implementation has been aggressively tuned, with custom separate `List<T>` / `T[]` / "everything else" implementations, and some other tricks to avoid unnecessarily chaining together iterators that could be done in a combined way. So again: why are you trying to do this? Heck, you could just *use `foreach`* if you think LINQ is causing you pain...

Comment: I see. Well I use LINQ and closures quite heavily in my codes. I wrote a drawing API for the editor in unity3d - the code there runs quite often, even more than once in a single frame. I profiled, LINQ generates a lot of garbage (the gc in unity is very outdated) which made things slower... converting all the linq queries in my code to use for/foreach loops is just... too much

Comment: @vexe your custom iterator blocks are going to generate *at least* as much garbage as LINQ does, and quite likely: more. I strongly suspect, however, that the garbage is not coming from where you think it is.

Comment: +1 for the `Consume` method which is handy for this kind of tasks if you don't want to measure anything else.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by another your test is flawed because none of the code is executed except the enumerator creation (you aren't materializing the sequences). But it's also flawed for a second reason, you're testing many times sure, but on extremely tiny sequences! Try the same tests on a lot more elements!

Comment: but testing the memory allocator is fun ;p